# If date range is provided return the logs in table within specific range else return all the logs in table where date is in time stamp —-oracle query

Tags: oracle

If date range is provided return the data  in table within specific range else return all the data in table where date is in timestamp —-oracle query

Comment: So what do you want here? SO is not a code-writing service, and even if it were, how would you expect somone to write a query without knowing anything about the tables involved or the nature of the inputs and desired outputs?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the question.

Based on Scott's `EMP` table which contains the `hiredate` column, I'll select values in a certain date range.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy'
  2  /

Session altered.

SQL> select ename, job, hiredate from emp order by hiredate;

ENAME      JOB       HIREDATE
---------- --------- ----------
SMITH      CLERK     17.12.1980
ALLEN      SALESMAN  20.02.1981
WARD       SALESMAN  22.02.1981
JONES      MANAGER   02.04.1981
BLAKE      MANAGER   01.05.1981      --> from here ...
CLARK      MANAGER   09.06.1981
TURNER     SALESMAN  08.09.1981
MARTIN     SALESMAN  28.09.1981
KING       PRESIDENT 17.11.1981      --> ... to here
JAMES      CLERK     03.12.1981
FORD       ANALYST   03.12.1981
MILLER     CLERK     23.01.1982
SCOTT      ANALYST   09.12.1982
ADAMS      CLERK     12.01.1983

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Query uses two parameters: date from (pass `01.05.1981`) and date to (pass `17.11.1981`). This is a "standard" way to deal with possibility of parameters being `NULL`. Example will run well in e.g. TOAD or SQL Developer.

```
select ename, job, hiredate
from emp
where (hiredate >= :par_date_from or :par_date_from is null)
  and (hiredate <= :par_date_to   or :par_date_to   is null)
order by hiredate;

ENAME      JOB       HIREDATE
---------- --------- ----------
BLAKE      MANAGER   01.05.1981
CLARK      MANAGER   09.06.1981
TURNER     SALESMAN  08.09.1981
MARTIN     SALESMAN  28.09.1981
KING       PRESIDENT 17.11.1981
```

If both parameters are `NULL`, all table rows are returned.